# how to use localstorage in next-auth when user authorize

Tags: authentication, next.js, local-storage, next.js13, next-auth

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import $api from "@/http";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credetials) {
        if (!credetials?.email || !credetials?.password) {
          return null;
        }
        const { email, password } = credetials;

        try {
          const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/login", {
            email,
            password,
          });

          if (res.data) {
            return res.data;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", user.tokens.access_token);
        }
        return { ...token, ...user };
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ token, session }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      session.tokens = token.tokens;

      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as POST, handler as GET };
```

I need to make sure that when the user logs in, I write down the accessToken that comes to localstorage, how can I do this here?

since I got an error due to the fact that localstorage cannot be run on the server, I checked on window, but it didn’t help.

and am I doing it right? I’m trying to get it in the jwt function, not authorize

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in `session` callback

```
async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
```

and access to session with `useSession` on client, `getServerSession` on the server. it is not safe to store in localStorage because`localStorage` is vulnerable to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks